# Data imported from CSV with PHP has broken hidden characters

Tags: php, mysql, csv, laravel, csv-import

I'm using the [Laravel Excel package](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/import) to import a CSV file into my application and am trying to match its data against my database.

The code so far is:

```
Excel::load($file, function($reader) { //Load it into Excel package
    $reader->each(function($row) { //Loop through row by row

        $firstname = $row->forename;
        $surname = $row->surname;

        $firstname = str_replace('"', '', $firstname); //Remove the enclosure "
        $surname = str_replace('"', '', $surname);

        $client = DB::table('clients')->where('firstname', $firstname)->where('surname', $surname)->first();

        if ($client!=null) {
            print $client->id."<br><br><br>";
        } else {
            print "Fail<br><br><br>";
        }
    });
})->get();
```

All queries fail, even when I am certain that a match should be made. Running some query debugging to get the query and bindings, I see this (sample data):

```
string 'select * from `clients` where `firstname` = ? and `surname` = ? limit 1' (length=71)

array (size=2)
  0 => string 'E�l�i�z�a�b�e�t�h' (length=17)
  1 => string '��W�e�s�s�o�n��' (length=15)
```

As you can see, all strings taken from the CSV have a � after every character.

I assume this could be some kind of encoding issue? Do I need to escape or process the strings from the CSV file before they can be used like normal PHP strings?

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code below, i found the same here 
http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/import#extra
check the '*Input encoding*' section 
Hope this helps

```
// When utilising a closure, you can pass the input encoding as third parameter.
Excel::load('filename.csv', function($reader) {

}, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that I tried that one and it didn't work.